# How can I build class similar to TransactionScope

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, transactionscope

Basically I'm trying to build something similar to transaction scope but to track changes in objects.

I have an abstract `RecordableObject` class roughly looking as follows:

```
public abstract class RecordableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        // remember previous values if recording is on
        var e = PropertyChanged;
        if (e != null)
        {
            e(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

    public void UndoChanges()
    {
    }

    public void StartRecording()
    {
    }

    public void SuspendRecording()
    {
    }

    public void StopRecording()
    {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And a recorder whom I want to manage all things:

```
public class ThreadStaticRecorder : IDisposable, IChangesRecorder
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static List<RecordableObject> recordingList;

    public void Record(RecordableObject recordableObject)
    {
        if (recordingList == null)
        {
            recordingList = new List<RecordableObject>();
        }

        recordingList.Add(recordableObject);
    }

    public void Forget(RecordableObject recordableObject)
    {
        if (recordingList == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        recordingList.Remove(recordableObject);
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        recordingList = null;
    }
}
```

Now, the point is I don't know how to tie recorder and recordable objects together, and I don't want recordable objects to know anything about recorder.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use it as follows:

```
public void TestRecorder(MyClass recorableObj)
{
    recorableObj.Foo = 1;
    using (var recorder = new ThreadStaticRecorder())
    {
         recorableObj.Foo = 2;
         recorder.Undo();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(recorableObj.Foo); // 1
}
```

Comment: CSLA can give you this sort of functionality. N-level undo, change tracking (broken rules, dirty properties), transactional save of object graphs, and business rules.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Memento` pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason TransactionScope works is that the objects affected by it all participate in the transaction system.  So in some sense they *do* "know about" the TransactionScope class.

What you have there is a cool idea, but I don't think there's anything in the "stock" .NET framework that would allow you to accomplish what you are attempting here without your recordable objects being aware of the recorder in some way.

Comment: OK, this doesn't really surprise me. Thanks! No im thinking of the best way to inject dependency on `IChangesRecorder` into `RecordableObject`. It's a little tricky due to tread-static fields.

Comment: @ArturUdod - yeah, I'm thinking you would need to have a base "RecordableObject" class that all other recordable objects decend from.  Then in the constructor for that base class you could have a call to "register" it with the ambient recorder if one exists.